# Ionic JSON, add card to favorites

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, favorites

I have a JSON Parse in my project and its work fine

```ts
let data:Observable<any>;

data = this.http.get(API);
data.subscribe(result => {
    this.items = result;
    this.saveData();
});
```

HTML:

```html
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-card-content id="{{item.id}}">
        ....
        ....
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Now I want a 'Favorite' function.

I have an icon with a click event.
How I do, that when anyone clicks on the icon he add the specific card to his favorites and he can show his favorites on another page?

Comment: what did u tried so far ?

Comment: I've been thinking about using the storage function or i safe it in a json file but im not sure what is better

Comment: You have to save the preference in a database when a user click

Comment: Local Storage will be best for this. If you have an API for user logins, I would recommend saving the storage tying the data to the users and putting the values in a service so the data can be used throughout the app.